# Can someone explain what happens technically when you use multiple instances of stereo widening?

Tags: super

Can someone explain what happens technically when you use multiple instances of stereo widening?

```
 After you throw one imager on the track, it widens it to an extent.  After you throw three more on, it strips the sound a little bit.
```

What is actually happening?

Is there a limit to how wide it can go?

How do we make things sound infinitely wide?

Answer (score 5):

When you widen a stereo sound, you usually increase the amount of out-of-phase information in the sound. These are the differences between the right and the left channel. The max amount of processing is when the two channels are completely out of phase, which doesn't sound wide but just gives the eerie feeling of not being able to locate the source of the sound. Out-of-phase audio cancels itself in mono.

Answer (score -2):

i can't explain it.  i think the sound gets deleted though once it reaches a certain point on the end points of the speaker cones